# Overlap Google Adsense on image

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, adsense

I would overlapp a google adsense message to an image.
[image]

I am using Twitter Bootstrap

```
<div id="row">
   <div id="span12">
   <img src="xxxxx"/ id="myimage"/>
   <div id="googleadsense">google adsense code
   </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to do this by applying a background image to your span12 div then position the google adsense div

**HTML**

```
<div id="row">
<div id="span12 myimage">
<div id="googleadsense">google adsense code </div>
</div>
<div>
```

CSS

```
.myimage{
position:relative: /* set so we can position the adsense child */
min-height:...;
background:#fff url('path/to/background-image.jpg') no-repeat left top;
}  

.googleadsense{
position:absolute:
top:0;
right:0;
}
```

Good luck!